# What is the TypeScript equivalent of React.PropTypes.node?

Tags: reactjs, typescript2.0

I have searched high and low, and I can find TypeScript equivalents for everything except React's `PropTypes.node`. I know that TypeScript doesn't need any `PropTypes`, but there are some `PropTypes` that I don't know how to convert to TypeScript.

Is it just as simple as `var node: any`? This doesn't seem right as `node` seems to have some properties.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `JSX.Element`, which is what I believe JSX itself resolves to.

Comment: Use React.ReactNode if your children can be null. Type definitions here: [DefinitelyTyped React.ReactNode](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L188), [JSX.Element](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L3622), [React.ReactElement](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L93)

Answer (score 59):

Use `React.ReactNode` for `React.PropTypes.node` type

Comment: This should actually be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 13):

## TypeScript for React developer

In Typescript, it has the checked type `React.ReactNode` which work the same as `React.PropTypes.node` in prop-types.

eg:

```
export interface PersonProps {
  children: (name: string, age: number) => React.ReactNode
}
```